# Facebook opengraph not showing shares for my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I am using graph.facebook.com/[url] method to read number of shares for my page but, the returned json doesn't seem to show any shares/comments on the page. I've manually shared the link of my page number of times but, It doesn't show up here.

Any Help would be appreciated. Here is the link to my page:
http://vlikeviral.com/videos/play?id=11
And this url I am using to detect the shares:
http://graph.facebook.com/http%3A%2F%2Fvlikeviral.com%2Fvideos%2Fplay%3Fid%3D11

Thanks in Advance.

Waqar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fvlikeviral.com%2Fvideos%2Fplay%3Fid%3D11

As you can see the reason why facebook is having issues is you need to define some og: meta tags.

See http://ogp.me for info on how to set these up correctly.

Comment: Thanks, adding og tags solved the problem. I can now see the share count!